# How to color just the wave produced by the ulem package

Tags: color, ulem

I am using `\uwave{Some text here}` to put a wave like emphasis under the text. Is it possible to change the color of only the wave and leave the text black?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is highly recommended that you post a minimal example. It is possible to only color the wave part by redefining the command `\uwave` or by creating a new command named `\redwave` as you like.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatletter
\def\uwave{\bgroup \markoverwith{\lower3.5\p@\hbox{\sixly \textcolor{red}{\char58}}}\ULon}
\font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory problem.
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \uwave{This is a long test}
\end{document}
```

The `ulem` package uses the wiggle from the 6-pt lasy font and we just use `textcolor` to color it.

One could extend the above code to give it a more semantic name, as suggested by TH and also to give an optional color. The MWE below defines a command `\colorwave` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\colorwave[1][blue]{\bgroup \markoverwith{\lower3.5\p@\hbox{\sixly \textcolor{#1}{\char58}}}\ULon}
\font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory problem.
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \colorwave[red]{This is a long test} \lipsum*[1].\par
 \colorwave[green]{This is a long test} \lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. One could make a `\colorwave` based on this where the color to use is passed in as an argument.

Comment: @TH Sure and it will be better rather than redefining the original command.

Comment: For thicker line consult [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67064/a-thicker-wave-underline) link. Or substitute:
lasy6 -> lasyb10 scaled 652

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\coloredwave}[2]{
    \textcolor{#1}{\uwave{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\coloredwave{red}{This text will be underlined with a red wavy line.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.