# How to color just the `\vec` symbol?

Tags: math-mode, color

How do I color only the vector symbol in `\vec f`? I'm using beamer, so xcolor is already loaded.

Extra "points" to an answer that also explains  how to fish..and not only gives me the fish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about

```
$\color{red}{\vec{\color{black}{f}}}$
```

and if you want it a bit more automated

```
\newcommand{\colorvec}[1]{{\color{red}\vec{\color{black}{#1}}}}
```

which is to be used as `$\colorvec{g}$`

[image]

Comment: What about `$\colorvec{a}+\colorvec{b}$`?

Comment: At least correct it.

Comment: @egreg done, by adding extra grouping {}

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\textcolor` that works also in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\rvec}[2][black]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\vec{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
}
\begin{document}
$\vec{x}$

$\rvec{x}$

$\rvec[green]{x}$
\end{document}
```

In this way you're sure that the color change will be limited to this object. I've added an optional argument to change also the color of the variable.

[image]

Comment: Great idea! love it! I'm surprised it didn't come up in other questions of this type.

Comment: @YossiFarjoun Probably because it's a bad idea to color the arrow. `;-)`

Comment: I meant, for example [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7321). I think that for a presentation, color is great when used sparingly...in this case, I want to have the arrow overlaid...so I want it in a different color to bring the attention to it...

Answer (score 1):

The question [How to color only a tilde accent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186157/how-to-color-only-a-tilde-accent-on-a-letter) was closed as "Duplicate" improper. There is very interesting problem which isn't solved in mentioned post nor here. When you return back to the black color in the nucleus of mathaccent atom, then this color manipulation needs `\special` or `\pdfliteral` and the skewchar correction of accent placement is lost. See the following example:

```
$\widetilde{E}\ \widetilde{\special{}E}\ \coloredaccent{red}\widetilde{E}$
```

which gives the result:

[image: colored accent problem]

Note that the second accent is positioned wrong because here is `\special` in the nucleus and the skewchar TeX positioning is lost. We need to return to the black color here which expands to such `\special` or `\pdfliteral`. How the third accent is created? This surprise follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newmuskip\tmpmudim  \newdimen\tmpdim

\def\coloredaccent#1#2#3{% #1=color, #2=accent, #3=nucleus
   {\ifnum\skewchar\textfont1<0 \tmpmudim=0mu
    \else \calculatemukern{#3}{\char\skewchar\textfont1 }
    \fi
    \colorlet{outcolor}{.}
    \color{#1}\mkern2\tmpmudim #2{\color{outcolor}\mkern-2\tmpmudim#3}
   }
}
\def\calculatemukern #1#2{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\textfont1 #1#2}\setbox1=\hbox{\the\textfont1 #1\null#2}%
   \tmpdim=\wd0 \advance\tmpdim by-\wd1
   \tmpmudim=\expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim mu \tmpmudim=288\tmpmudim
   \tmpdim=16em \divide\tmpmudim
   by\expandafter\ignorefracpart\the\tmpdim\relax
}
\def\ignorefracpart#1.#2\relax{#1}
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{E}\ \widetilde{\special{}E}\ \coloredaccent{red}\widetilde{E}$

\end{document}
```

We need to emulate the skewchar kerning (implemented in TeX) by macros. First, we do measurement of kern between nulcelus and skewchar. The result is in pt. Second, we convert this result to the mu units in order to the result is applicable in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscripstyle` too. Finally, the `\mkern2\tmpmudim` and `\mkern-2\tmpmudim` is used to the correction of the accent placement.