# Is it possible to give colors to big (automatic) parenthesis in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, color, brackets

In the following code I can't make the right parenthesis to have arbitrary colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{44}{55}{\color{blue}\right)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As soon as I add `color` around `\right)` (or `\left(`) I get an error: `! Missing } inserted.`

Is there a work around for this? (I prefer not to touch other parts of the equation).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103325/colored-underbraces-for-annotating-equations

Comment: Just for you to know why it didn't work: you enclose `\right)` in the group without `\left(`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125795/defining-a-macro-for-real-colored-delimiters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really easier: `\left` and `\right` form a group, so setting the color immediately before `\right` will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{44}{55}\color{red}\right)+2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For coloring also the left delimiter, you can save the color before changing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begingroup
\colorlet{savedleftcolor}{.}
\color{blue}\left(\color{savedleftcolor}
  \frac{44}{55}\color{red}\right)
\endgroup
+2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A generalized version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cleft}[2][.]{%
  \begingroup\colorlet{savedleftcolor}{.}%
  \color{#1}\left#2\color{savedleftcolor}%
}
\newcommand{\cright}[2][.]{%
  \color{#1}\right#2\endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\cleft[blue](\frac{44}{55}\cright[red])
+
\cleft[red](\frac{44}{55}\cright)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\cleft{[}` is needed for having the bracket, if no color is specified, or `\cleft\lbrack`.

Don't try closing `\cleft` with `\right` or `\left` with `\cright`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

How to do things so complicatedly when there is a simple alternative?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{44}{55}\color{blue}\right)\color{black}        
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last just be `\normalcolor`?

Comment: May be Yes. I'am not specialist of (x)color packages and any others LaTeX packages:)

Comment: There should be way to remember the colour before it gets changed, then the code could be modified to behave exactly as if the colour command was grouped. And +1 for a genuine idea! :)

Comment: Yes. `\colorlet{outcolor}{.}` to remember current color and `\color{outcolor}` to restore it. See for example my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/how-to-color-just-the-vec-symbol/186226#186226 This is more complicated case because the kerning problem have to be solved there. This problem isn't here during typesetting only parenthesis.

Comment: Resetting `\color{black}` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Ugly, but works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{44}{55}\right.{\color{blue}\left.\mkern-7mu\vphantom{\frac{44}{55}}\right)}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe explain how you arrived at the `\mkern-7mu` spacing adjustment? Mainly by "occular regression", or by a somewhat more explicit method?

Comment: @Mico eye balling! ;)