# Is it possible to add a background color just to an accent?

Tags: accents, backgrounds, highlighting, katex

For something like `\hat{w}` or `\vec{v}` is it possible to set the background color for just the accent, *i.e.*, the background of `w` and `v` would be normal, but the circumflex and vector symbol would be highlighted?

I'm trying this on KaTeX, where most of the styling is handled by HTML commands; however, I'm interested in any tex-based solutions.

Comment: Did you see this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46701/47927 ?

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks, I hadn't seen that one, in my searches; however, I had tried an analogous approach with KaTeX's `\htmlStyle{background-color:...}` which didn't work. I'll have to have a closer look at the solutions to see if any could be generalized to a bg colour. Thanks for taking the time to link a similar question!

Answer (score 2):

This in some ways does what you are asking for, but may be more suitable to talk you out of this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{contour} 
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\contourlength{0.2pt}\contour{blue}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}}{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but this could be a viable alternative -- thanks for taking the time to share! Didn't know we could do this & love discovering new options.