# A thicker wave underline

Tags: rules, text-decorations, ulem

I have found `\uwave` in the [`ulem` package](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf), and its definition in [`ulem.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.sty):

```
% Now define various special underlines.  All the definitions go like
% \def \command {\bgroup \markoverwith{something} \ULon}

% For drawing a wavey underline instead of a straight one the command
% is \uwave (under-wave) which uses the wiggle from 6-pt lasy font:

\def\uwave{\bgroup \markoverwith{\lower3.5\p@\hbox{\sixly \char58}}\ULon}
\font\sixly=lasy6 % does not re-load if already loaded, so no memory problem.
```

I would like to keep the underline wave, but **much thicker**, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 13):

There is a bold variant of the `lasy` fonts: `lasyb10`. Some scaling is needed to
fit the width of the character of font `lasy6` (e.g., because of different design size).

The example is plain TeX syntax, therefore I keep it.

```
% plain TeX    
\input ulem.sty\relax
\catcode`\@=11 %

\font\uwavefontold=lasy6
\font\uwavefont=lasyb10 scaled 652

\def\uwaveold{%
  \bgroup
    \markoverwith{%
      \lower3.5\p@\hbox{\uwavefontold\char58}%
    }%
  \ULon
}
\def\uwave{%
  \bgroup
    \markoverwith{%
      \lower3.5\p@\hbox{\uwavefont\char58}%
    }%
  \ULon
}

\uwaveold{Hello World}

\uwave{Hello World}

\bye
```

Compare the result:

> [image: uwave with lasy6 and lasyb10]