# Strikeout - when which package ? ( ulem vs soul vs ...)

Tags: packages, text-decorations, soul, strikeout, ulem

When to use which package for strikeout?

I see answers :

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\sout{Hello World}
```

or

```
\usepackage{soul}
\st{Hello world}
```

or

```
\usepackage{cancel}
\cancel{Hello world}
```

In what situations is it best to use which one?

Maybe there are other packages I am not aware of?

Shouldn't be there one standard way to strikeout?

Comment: To me the largest difference is that `ulem` feels like a tool for underlining etc. whereas the `SOUL` package feels more like a general toolkit for creating text decoration macros that comes with a few pre-defined commands that show you how to use it.

Comment: Maybe someone that knows could comment on this: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg147217.html

Comment: You should also consider soulpos that combines soul with the savepos mechanism so that you
can arbitrary underlining and decorations, including rules, leaders and even pictures. Unlike soul underlines, which are
built by repeating small elements, here each chunk of
text to be underlined is a single element.

Comment: Remark, the way `soul` works as far as I can see requires the overlay to be "horizontally uniform", so for wavy lines such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67064/a-thicker-wave-underline, you have to stick to `ulem` (as mentioned below does not allow automatic hyphenation) or `soulpos` (needs two compilation passes).

Comment: Another note is with characters with diacritics, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142359/250119 for an example.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`cancel` is intended for indicating mathematic cancellation, and consequently only works in math mode; it also strikes out diagnoally.

`soul` and `ulem` seem pretty similar. One basic semantic difference between them is that `ulem` per default changes the definition of `\emph{...}` to underline its argument instead of putting it in italics. This seems to aim at the reproduction of typewriter typesetting, when underlining often was the only means of indicating emphasis. Since using underlining for emphasis is mostly deprecated nowadays, I've always used `soul` when I did need to underline something.

The one **big reason in favor of `soul`**, however, is that it's able to deal with line breaks and hyphenation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth=1cm % just to force hyphenation to happen

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cancel,soul,ulem}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\cancel{5}*17}{\cancel{5}*23}
\]

X \sout{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

X \st{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

X \emph{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

X \ul{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
\end{document}
```

(The `X` are necessary because LaTeX won't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph.)

[image: output]

Comment: It should probably also be mentioned that `ulem` has the package option `normalem`, which does not make `\emph` underline its argument. This way you can get the `\sout` command without changing the behavior of `\emph`.

Comment: Just an addition: It is possible to set explicit hyphenation points in `ulem` using `\-`. Those work.

Comment: "typewriter typesetting, when underlining often was the only means of indicating emphasis" All manual typewriters had bold because you could type over the text a second time which was a real test of accurate typing. That was also how you created composite characters like diacritics or slashed zero. You could also overtype a / or X to represent crossed out but I was taught it was quicker to draw a ruled line with a pen and remember to do the same for the carbon copy.

Comment: From the 12-Apr-2013 version of `cancel` '[`\cancel` `\bcancel` and `xcancel`] work in math and text mode, but `\cancelto` is only for math mode.'

Comment: AFAIK, soul can't double underline.