# Follow-up: Underline + strike-through using soul

Tags: formatting, text-decorations, soul

This is a follow-up question to [Mixing underline and strike-out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176111/5764). This time, I'm specifically interested in an implementation using [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) (that doesn't require multiple compilations to stabilize).

I would like to use `soul` to create an (underline) + (strike-through) command `\textulst` that would combine `\textul` with `\textst` and still allow line-breaks within.

Thus far I'm unable to properly combine the two, as `soul` uses the same underlining for *both* the (regular) underline and the strike-through.

Here's my (unsuccessful) attempt at generating `\textulst`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@ulstunderline#1{{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#1}%
    \dimen@=\wd\z@
    \dimen@i=\SOUL@uloverlap
    \advance\dimen@2\dimen@i
    \rlap{% Draw underline
        \null
        \kern-\dimen@i
        \SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@ulleaders\hskip\dimen@}%
    }%
    \SOUL@stpreamble% Switch to draw over-strike
    \rlap{%
        \null
        \kern-\dimen@i
        \SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@ulleaders\hskip\dimen@}%
    }%
    \unhcopy\z@
}}
\def\SOUL@ulsteverysyllable{%
    \SOUL@ulstunderline{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
}
\def\SOUL@ulstsetup{%
  \SOUL@ulsetup
  \let\SOUL@everysyllable\SOUL@ulsteverysyllable
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textulst{\SOUL@ulstsetup\SOUL@}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Here is \textul{some text}.

Here is \textst{some text}.

Here is \textulst{some text}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between underlining and striking text the usual way and using packages like `soul` and `censor` ?

Comment: @subhamsoni: As mentioned in [Mixing underline and strike-out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176111/5764), [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) cannot handle nesting. Also, [as mentioned below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178654/follow-up-underline-strike-through-using-soul/178701?noredirect=1#comment412540_178691), [`censor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/censor) does not handle hyphenation properly. The solution proposed in the linked question in awesome (and uses [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), but requires multiple compiles (even first time around) to settle the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution based on `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\SOUL@ulstdp
\newdimen\SOUL@ulstht
\def\SOUL@ulstleaders{%
    \leaders
    \hbox
    {%
      \rlap{\vrule\@depth\SOUL@uldp\@height\SOUL@ulht\@width.1pt\relax}%
      \vrule\@depth\SOUL@ulstdp\@height\SOUL@ulstht\@width.1pt\relax
    }%
}
\def\SOUL@ulstpreamble{%
  \SOUL@ulpreamble
  \SOUL@ulstdp=\SOUL@uldp
  \SOUL@ulstht=\SOUL@ulht
  \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\def\SOUL@ulstsetup{%
  \SOUL@ulsetup
  \let\SOUL@preamble\SOUL@ulstpreamble
  \let\SOUL@ulleaders\SOUL@ulstleaders
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textulst{\SOUL@ulstsetup\SOUL@}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Here is \textul{some text}.

Here is \textst{some text}.

Here is \textulst{some text}.
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

It's based on the idea of "stacking" two rules immediately in the `\leaders` construction `soul` uses to overlay a rule. I wouldn't know how else to get two rules as soul relies heavily on `\leaders` especially to support stretching interword space.

The downside is that when using `\leaders` with a rule (as usual for `\ul`, `\st`, and `\hl`), the rule will just stretch as far as the dimension given as the leader length, while when using a box, the rule needs to have a predefined width, which then becomes the minimal length of the leaders construct. The box is then replicated as often as neccessary to span the given width.

I have used `.1pt` as the box width. That means, if `soul` tries to span something shorter than `.1pt` there will be a gap in the underline. On the other hand, using a narrower box will substantially enlarge execution time and file size.

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this doesn't answer your question because it is not with `soul`, but rather this shows an alternative, using `censor`, based on several of my similar previous answers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\uldepth
\newlength\rlwd
\def\ulcolor{black}
\rlwd=.8pt
\censorruledepth=2.5pt
\uldepth=-2pt

\makeatletter
\def\stacktype{L}
\periodrlap=0pt\relax
\afterperiodlap=0pt\relax
\lletterlap=0pt\relax
\rletterlap=0pt\relax
\afterspacelap=1.0ex\relax

\renewcommand\censorrule[1]{%
\protect\textcolor{\ulcolor}{\stackon[0pt]%
  {\rule[\uldepth]{#1}{\rlwd}}{\rule[\censorruledepth]{#1}{\rlwd}}}%
}

\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \stackon[0pt]{#1}{\censorrule{\wd0}}%
}

\def\censordot{\textcolor{\ulcolor}{\rlap{\@cenword{\phantom{.}}}}.}

\makeatother
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}

This shows linebreaking capability: aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
\xblackout{bbb bbb bbb bbb. bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb}
ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc

Can this \xblackout{procedure go across paragraphs boundaries?

Why yes} it can.![enter image description here][1]

But gaps can arise if glue is stretched too far.

\afterspacelap=1.7ex\relax
\xblackout{%
This tests marking a multiline block of text.  This tests marking a multiline block of text.
This tests marking a multiline block of text.  This tests marking a multiline block of text.
This tests marking a multiline block of text.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this support hyphenation?

Comment: @StephanLehmke No, the censor package algorithm does not support hyphenation.