# StrikeThrough (st) command drops the Unicode letters

Tags: unicode, strikeout

The `\st` command drops the Unicode letters coming at the end.

I use LuaLatex most of the time on TexLive 2020.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt,oneside,]{extbook}

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\strkfade}[1]
           {{\color{black!50}\st{#1}}}
           

\begin{document}

This is normal text.

\strkfade{This is striked through faded text}

This is striked through faded Unicode text, which prints correctly: \strkfade{distance between İstanbul - Iğdır}

This is striked through faded Unicode text, which prints uncorrectly: \strkfade{Iğdırı}. It must have printed \emph{Iğdırı} i.e. an ``ı'' at the end. But it drops that ``ı''.
\end{document}
```

How to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**
My question has been closed by leaving this link: [soul dropping some accented letters from the end of words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/soul-dropping-some-accented-letters-from-the-end-of-words)

I've tried the solution in the link but it didn't work, see the note below.

**NOTE** She solution suggested adding these codes

```
\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\relax
\newfontface{\SOUL@tt}{FreeMono}
\makeatother
```

after loading the `soul` After I've applied it, I got this error:

`! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.`

Comment: Which engine do you use?

Comment: With XeLaTeX, I get 11 errors like "Missing character: There is no İ ("130) in font ectt1000!".  Two for "İ ("130)", four for "ğ ("11F)", and five for "ı ("131)".

Comment: I use lualatex most of the time.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen For your interest: No moderator of this site was involved in marking your question as duplicate.

Comment: If no moderator has closed down my question then who did it? Some AI bot?

Comment: 3 regular community members. Could you word your appeal in a bit more neutral way? The chances for reopening might be better then ...

Comment: (if you are using lualatex, why use soul? lua-ul is more robust and solves a lot of the limitations of soul, including the problem you are asking about)

Comment: How to use that `lua-ul` I've tried: `\usepackage{lua-ul}` but then it complained with: , ! Undefined control sequence. \strkfade #1 -{\color {black!50} ...`

Comment: here is an example for lua-ul https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533377/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the comment. Actually, I've solved the problem just a while ago, after taking a look at the lua-ul package's CTAN page. There in the PDF documentation, the required command was given as `strikeThrough` (in the place of `st`) So I've renamed the `st` to `strikeThrough`  and there you go. It worked out!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've solved the problem after adding `\usepackage{lua-ul}` and replacing `st` with the lua-ul's `strikeThrough` If you feel like, you could post this as an answer and I'd select it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: you can use \st if you load the package with the option soul:  `\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}`

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen I added an answer, but please take some time to edit your question and remove unfair statements like "This act of closing has caused more harm than good, by depriving my question of the views it deserved." The only reason I saw your question and suggested lua-ul was because I came across it in the review queue - something that would never have happened if your question had not been closed. You probably have gotten *more* views because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using lualatex, there is really no good reason to use `soul` when there is the fantastic `lua-ul` package:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt,oneside,]{extbook}

\usepackage{lua-ul} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\strkfade}[1]
           {{\color{black!50}\strikeThrough{#1}}}
           

\begin{document}

This is normal text.

\strkfade{This is striked through faded text}

This is striked through faded Unicode text, which prints correctly: \strkfade{distance between İstanbul - Iğdır}

This is striked through faded Unicode text, which prints uncorrectly: \strkfade{Iğdırı}. It must have printed \emph{Iğdırı} i.e. an ``ı'' at the end. But it drops that ``ı''.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: `soul`and `soulutf8`have been merged:

> This version is a merge of the original soul package from Melchior Franz and the soulutf8 package from Heiko Oberdiek and supports also UTF8.

---

You can use the package [`soulutf8`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8)

### Result

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried it but the problem is still there. It drops the last `ı`

Comment: @anis Could you post the code you used to get this screen shot?  My attempt at doing this on Overleaf doesn't have the character that yours does.

Comment: I just replaced `\usepackage{soul}` with `\usepackage{soulutf8}` , ocmpiling with pdflatex

Comment: Just for the record: I almost never use `pdflatex` because (if I remember correctly) it doesn't support Unicode text. The `lualatex` in contrast supports every kind of texts and it doesn't bring any drawbacks by doing so.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen "it doesn't bring any drawbacks by doing so." -> it *is* slower