# Highlighting and striking through text in latex

Tags: soul

I have used

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
\hl{\mbox{\sout{This is my text which I want to highlight and strike through. The text does not go to the next line, instead it goes beyond the page.}}}
\end{document}
```

But the sentence is not broken down in output pages. It goes beyond the page. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Why you use \mbox? It prevent to break text in it. Try to remove it. If you like to get an answer, please provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko If you use without mbox, it says reconstruction failed.

Comment: Please post the `MWE` as in executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Please provide MWE that we can see what you doing,

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: This is not sufficient. Please provide complete document )beginning with ˙\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}, which can test at it is

Comment: I've updated the question again

Comment: Read package documentation, section **, paragraph  22. What you doing is not supported.

Comment: So, how do you highlight and strikethrough same text (i.e. a paragraph) in latex?

Comment: Just wondering, why you do that. If you want to comment, redact etc. like with Acrobat there are packages supporting this in Latex.

Comment: @MS-SPO May I know what packages you are referring to? Thank you

Comment: @YatShan, Because you (still) didn‘t mention your reason, I suggest entering one of these search terms into your search engine: ctan comment, ctan redact, and similar. Check out package manuals. Also have a look at the classifications ctan.org provides, leading you to similar or better packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing underline and strike-out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/mixing-underline-and-strike-out)

Comment: @user202729 No, the answers over there use tikz package

Comment: What's wrong with that? `soulpos` package also uses TikZ for positioning

Comment: In retrospect that answer is not specifically for this question, but **one of** the macros defined in that specific answer does work here.

Comment: The answer from that link looks very complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest would be to use `soulpos`:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ulposdef{\hlst}{%
    \rlap{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.75ex]{\ulwidth}{2.5ex}}}%
    \rule[.45ex]{\ulwidth}{.1ex}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\textbf{New hlst macro:}

\hlst{This is my text which I want to highlight and strike through. The text goes to the next line instead of going beyond the page.}

\textbf{hl:}

\hl{This is my text which I want to highlight and strike through. The text goes to the next line instead of going beyond the page.}

\textbf{st:}

\st{This is my text which I want to highlight and strike through. The text goes to the next line instead of going beyond the page.}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

Another alternative is to use `lua-ul` see [Can't underline highlighted text (soul)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418101/cant-underline-highlighted-text-soul/533377#533377) for an example.

Comment: This solution works. But for some reason, in the main latex project it is not either highlighting or striking through the text.

Comment: @YatShan Without a minimal working example I can't tell anything. (remember that you need to compile twice, soulpos requires 2 passes.)

Comment: Even after two compilations, it didn't work.

Comment: @YatShan Need minimal non-working example then.