Coloring a word in underlined sentence (with \ul from soul package)
In the following code, I am trying to coloring a select word/letter in a underlined phrase.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\calert}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Are there explicit continuous $f,g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. \ul{$f$ is subsubnet \calert{left-}RS-integrable (ssn\calert{L}RSI?) w.r.t. $g$} but not \ul{\calert{L}RSI}? What about $(f,g)$ a \ul{ssnRSI-pair} but not \ul{RSI-pair}?

\end{document}

If I replace all \ul with \underline, it works
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\calert}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Are there explicit continuous $f,g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. \underline{$f$ is subsubnet \calert{left-}RS-integrable (ssn\calert{L}RSI?) w.r.t. $g$} but not \underline{\calert{L}RSI}? What about $(f,g)$ a \underline{ssnRSI-pair} but not \underline{RSI-pair}?

\end{document}

but as usual with \underline, it does not text-wrap. I also tried \uline which was also mentioned here: Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?, and it did work. But I'm just curious why things failed with \ul.

Consider reviewing Cool text highlighting in LaTeX.

use lualatex and the lua-ul package. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533377/2388


But I'm just curious why things failed with \ul.

Everyone says how, but it's difficult to find an answer that says why. (Many people have linked more working suggestions in the comments. Though if you know a older more popular answered question on this site that asks the "why" it's probably better for the site to link to that question as a duplicate.)
Anyway, it's explained in the documentation:


tl;dr: in order to support underlining, soul package need to parse the TeX source code, which is a difficult task and might fail to do the correct thing on encountering unexpected macros such as the \calert you used in the question.
Of course, fast forward 20 years after the soul package is written, LuaLaTeX supports writing underline macros that actually works in all cases. (lua-ul package uses some Lua hooks/callbacks.)
Anyway, for soul, it actually has a mechanism to support what you want (but line break within the command is then not supported…)

Probably \soulregister{\calert}{1} suffices.

@cfr I added these as alt text.

thanks. I thought my browser would show alt text if I hovered, but apparently not. apologies again. (comments deleted.)

@cfr Not really, I only add them after you point it out. So thanks.
