# highlight and strikethrough with soul

Tags: soul, changes

I would like to highlight and strike through a text via the latex package soul.

I'm pretty sure this can be solved via the answer

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178701#178701

Unfortunately, I am not able to do this myself. I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: Clarification question: what do you mean with "I am not able to do this myself"? Did you get an error when you tried the code from the linked answer, and if yes, what was the error message? Or are you unsure about which parts of that answer to code to your own document? Or do you want something extra that is not covered by that answer, and if so, what do you want to get as output exactly?

Comment: Sorry when is was not specific enough. The linked answer works well. I need an adapted variant of the linked answer. A comand like texthlst{some}, which allows me to hightlight and strikethrough a text part. The linked anwser does this for underlining and strikethrough, but not hightlighting. I tried by myself to adapt the solution of the linked anwser, but my tex skills are not sufficient for this.

Comment: If you are willing to use `ulem` instead of `soul` then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411637/highlighting-strikeout-text-with-ulem-shifts-the-line-downwards would be applicable I think.

Comment: Four `soul` itself my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418101/cant-underline-highlighted-text-soul (with `\sbox`) can be used.

Comment: Thank you, but both solutions do not allow a line break...the linked answer can handle line breaks

Comment: In my testing the second answer with `lua-ul` does support line break, consider question solved then. (however that one is for LuaLaTeX only and it's underline+highlight instead of strikethrough+highlight)