# Changes package - highlight and strikethrough

Tags: soul, changes

I am working with the changes and soul package. Highlighting DELETED passages works well with `\sethcolor` and `hl` command:

```
\setdeletedmarkup{\sethlcolor{green}{\hl{#1}}}
```

Is it possible to combine the highlighting with strikethrough command (`\sout`) for the deleted markup?

Comment: Nesting commands from the `soul` package can be done (See the documentation) by boxing the material; this, of course, doesn't allow for line breaks anymore. For a solution allowing line breaks, see [`Peter Grill's answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176118/3954) to [`Mixing underline and strike-out`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176111/3954)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the solution from Peter Grill just working with a semitransparent box?