# highlighting strikeout text with ulem shifts the line downwards

Tags: highlighting, ulem, strikeout

I'm trying to highlight a text with a strikeout word by defining a new command as explained in the docs of `ulem`. Unfortunately, that moves down the strikeout line a few points, which looks strange compared to non-highlighted text. How to avoid/fix this?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.

\hl{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related question: [formatting - Mixing underline and strike-out - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/mixing-underline-and-strike-out/685473#685473) ;; [soul - Highlighting and striking through text in latex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685469/highlighting-and-striking-through-text-in-latex?noredirect=1#comment1700691_685469)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let `\hl` redefine the `\sout` marco (the space in the name is important).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\hl{%
  \bgroup
  \expandafter\def\csname sout\space\endcsname{\bgroup \ULdepth =-.8ex \ULset}%
  \markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}}%
  \ULon}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.

\hl{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** thanks to [muzimuzhiZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411637/highlighting-strikeout-text-with-ulem-shifts-the-line-downwards/411709?noredirect=1#comment1341258_411709) for letting me know that the above became outdated.

If you're using a newer version of `ulem` starting from 2019-11-28, the `\sout` macro isn't changed by the above, since it is now defined as `\protected\def\sout{...}` instead. You can use the following then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hl{%
  \bgroup
  \UL@protected\def\sout{\bgroup \ULdepth =-.8ex \ULset}%
  \markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}}%
  \ULon}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.

\hl{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \sout{and typesetting} industry.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, highlighting across line breaks won't work:

`This is \hl{a new paragraph.

And so} is this.`

Could https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247009/153215 solve this problem, too?

Comment: @MathiasWalter you could try. It looks good, but I won't test this myself.

Comment: I've tried this with the mentiond wrapper command and it works.
I wonder if it's possible to integrate it into your solution. I don't have much experience in writing tex macros and stuck on the paratmeter #1.

Comment: My answer does redefine an internal command of the `ulem` package locally. Just using the code there with replacing every occurence of `xout` with `hl` should work (untested).

Comment: yes, this works. I just wanted to avoid introducing two additional commands (`parhelp` and `hlpars` which wraps your solution with `helpcmd/parhelp`). But anyway, it works. Thanks!

Comment: One additional problem arose in combination with chapter titles. If a chapter spans multiple pages, the chapter title is printed in the header - including the highlighted part. How can I avoid this? I tried \let\MakeUppercase=\relax. But then I get the LaTeX Error: "Not in outer par mode."

Comment: Found the answer myself: I used the optional argument of \chapter with the unmodified/undecorated text.

Comment: From `ulem` 2019/11/18, `\sout` is defined directly by `\protected\def`, so the `\expandafter\def\csname sout\space\endcsname` part should be changed to `\UL@protected\def`. The detailed changes of `ulem` 2019/11/18 can been seen here.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting observation and here comes an overkill answer based on Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\HighLight{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}

\tikzset{StrikeOut/.style={thick,-}}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58590/121799
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \global\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \global\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\StrikeOut}[2][2pt]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(Begin.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (Begin) {\strut};}#2%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(End.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (End) {\strut};}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxN}{\BeginyN}
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}%\typeout{\BeginyN\space\EndyN}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\EndyN-\BeginyN}
\ifnum\mytest=0\relax% begin and and in the same line %\typeout{begin and end in the same line}
% \draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$)
% -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- cycle;
\draw[StrikeOut] (Begin) -- (End);
\else% \typeout{end below begin}
\path (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south west)
node(WestLine)[left]{};
\path (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south east)
node(EastLine)[right]{};
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.south)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxS}{\BeginyS}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginyS-\EndyN+1pt}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest<2\relax% \typeout{end in the next line after begin}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginxS-\EndxN}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest>0\relax
% \draw[thick,-] (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- 
% ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) -- (Begin.south -| EastLine);
\draw[StrikeOut] (Begin) -- (Begin -| EastLine);
% \draw[thick,-] (End.south -| WestLine) -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- 
% ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| WestLine);
\draw[StrikeOut] (End -| WestLine) -- (End);
\else
% \draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) -- 
% (Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
% -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
% -- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\draw[StrikeOut] (Begin) -- (Begin -| EastLine);
\draw[StrikeOut] (End -| WestLine) -- (End);
\fi
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LineHeight}{\the\baselineskip}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumLines}{-1+(\BeginyN-\EndyN)/\LineHeight}
\typeout{\NumLines}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\NumLines}
{
\draw[StrikeOut] ($(Begin -| WestLine)+(0,-\X*\LineHeight pt)$) -- 
($(Begin -|EastLine)+(0,-\X*\LineHeight pt)$);
}
\draw[StrikeOut] (Begin) -- (Begin -| EastLine);
\draw[StrikeOut] (End -| WestLine) -- (End);
% \draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) -- 
% (Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
% -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
% -- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \StrikeOut{and typesetting} industry.

\HighLight{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing \StrikeOut{and typesetting} industry.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \StrikeOut{Sed a leo ut
erat luctus scelerisque. Suspendisse auctor mauris sit amet fringilla
hendrerit.} Maecenas eu tortor eu diam fringilla scelerisque sit amet eget enim.
Nam vitae bibendum erat, sit amet scelerisque felis. \StrikeOut{Suspendisse placerat
vitae velit pharetra lobortis et marmottae.} Donec ut erat a erat porta aliquet. Nulla eget
augue sem. Proin orci neque, eleifend id eleifend id, venenatis sit amet diam.
\StrikeOut{Mauris lacus est, cursus eget sapien at, pharetra lobortis ante. Proin
tempus ipsum tellus, ut ultricies magna congue nec. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse potenti.
In posuere dapibus urna, vitae euismod magna iaculis at.} Pellentesque pretium,
lorem ut vehicula egestas, velit dolor porta nunc, id interdum ipsum purus vel
dolor.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This workaround has all sorts of drawbacks, such as the inability to deal with page breaks and that does not work when the height of the line changes inside the `\StrikeOut` argument. The code is based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/121799). I'm only posting it here because I wanted to convince myself that it can be done in principle while not destroying the hyphenation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used the same command name as provided by the `soul` package, because before I've used the soul package, too and switched between various versions without having to change my whole document. It is simply for testing purposes/MWE. Unfortunately, `\hl` or `\texthl` from the `soul` package is not compatible with the changes package (which uses ulem), because the highlighting stops as soon as text or character is marked (striked/exed out, underlined, etc.).

Comment: My main aim is to get highlighting of some changes or part of changes working. I'm aware of the solution provided in [Changes package - highlight and strikethrough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249822/changes-package-highlight-and-strikethrough) but I don't want to replace strikethrough by highlighting and I don't want to have the drawbacks you mentioned above.

Comment: I just recognized that the original `\sout` isn't linebreakable either inside of `\hl`. I don't know however for which reason that is.

Comment: @Skillmon I thought it never is, i.e. even outside `\hl`, at least according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74910/121799): "The one big reason in favor of soul, however, is that it's able to deal with line breaks and hyphenation:"

Comment: Line breaking does work (at least in between words) using `\sout` outside of `\hl`. But no hyphenation it seems.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, you're right. I was not precise. I was also thinking to use [these tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/121799) in order to write a line- and word-breakable strike through in Ti*k*Z, but I am not sure if that would just be "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: @marmot please go ahead. I'm personally interested in this as I encountered a use case where `soul` doesn't work but `ulem` does with the restriction of no automatic hyphenation and perhaps your Ti*k*Z solution would work, too.

Comment: @marmot I tried to implement the stuff you provided [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/121799) with underlining. The code works well outside of `\hl`. But inside of it, line breaking doesn't work with it (maybe my fault?!).

Comment: @Skillmon I can't say much because I don't see your code. I plan to write up what I'm thinking over the weekend.

Comment: @marmot of course you can't. And the issues with page breaks remain, too. I don't know what you intend to write up, I just wanted to warn you that it might not work out.

Comment: I think there is no need for `\LineHeight`. Ti*k*Z should understand `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Line wrapping (overfull boxes) of `\StrikeOut` inside `\HighLight` doesn't work this way. I warned you beforehand that it might not work :)

Comment: @Skillmon Ah, I misinterpreted what you said. BTW, if one does the highlights with the \BoxMe thingy, it will work.