# How to produce the double wave underline?

Tags: underline

I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a double waveline. And I wish the underline could have line break automatically. Is there any methods to use \dwave(double wavy underline) as follow?
For example, using `\dwave{I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \dwave and have the line break result?}`

I want to have a effect like
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the definition of `uwave`:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}


\makeatletter

\iffalse  % the following is the default definition of \uwave for comparison. Commented out.
\protected\def\uwave{%
\leavevmode \bgroup
\ifdim \ULdepth =\maxdimen \ULdepth 3.5\p@ \else \advance \ULdepth 2\p@ \fi
\markoverwith {\lower \ULdepth \hbox {\sixly \char 58}}%
\ULon 
}
\fi

% and this is the definition of dwave.
\protected\def\dwave{%
\leavevmode \bgroup
\markoverwith {%
\lower 3.5\p@ \hb@xt@ \z@{\sixly \char 58\hss}%
\lower 5\p@ \hbox {\sixly \char 58}%
}%
\ULon 
}

\makeatother

\uwave{%
    I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \textbackslash dwave and have the line break result?%
}

\dwave{%
    I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \textbackslash dwave and have the line break result?%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output image]

(documentation of primitive commands in TeXbook/TeX by Topic as usual.) Otherwise you can roughly guess how `\markoverwith ... \ULon` are meant to be used in the `ulem` documentation. Reading the code you can figure out that the original definition of `uwave` is used to make sure that nesting multiple emphasis will lower the outer definition, but nesting does not line-break properly anyway so we need to define a custom command.

---

Alternative solution using `soulpos` which [has the advantage of supporting word-break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74893/strikeout-when-which-package-ulem-vs-soul-vs) (but takes one additional compilation pass):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}


\makeatletter


% this is taken straight from the documentation.
\ulposdef{\uwave}{%
\raisebox{-.75ex}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\clip (0,-1pt) rectangle (\ulwidth,1pt);
\draw[color=black!40,
line width=.7pt,
decorate,
decoration=
{snake,
amplitude=.3pt,
segment length=1mm,}]
(0,0) -- +(\ulwidth+3pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}}

% copied.
\ulposdef{\dwave}{%
\raisebox{-.9ex}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mylinestyle/.style={
            color=black,
            decorate,
            decoration={snake, amplitude=.3pt, segment length=1mm}
        }]%
        \clip (0,-1pt) rectangle (\ulwidth,3pt);
        \draw[mylinestyle] (0,0) -- +(\ulwidth+3pt,0);
        \draw[mylinestyle] (0,1.5pt) -- +(\ulwidth+3pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}}


\makeatother

\uwave{%
    I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \textbackslash dwave and have the line break result?%
}

\dwave{%
    I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \textbackslash dwave and have the line break result?%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of soulbox]

---

Yet another alternative is to use `lua-ul` -- allows hyphenation, requires only one compilation pass, but requires LuaLaTeX:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lua-ul}



\newunderlinetype\beginDoubleUnderWavy[\number\dimexpr1ex]{\cleaders\hbox{%
\setlength\unitlength{.3ex}%
\begin{picture}(4,0)(0,1)
\qbezier(0,0)(1,1)(2,0) \qbezier(2,0)(3,-1)(4,0)  % the original underline
\qbezier(0,-1)(1,0)(2,-1) \qbezier(2,-1)(3,-2)(4,-1)  % the underline below
\end{picture}%
}}
\NewDocumentCommand\doubleUnderWavy{+m}{{\beginDoubleUnderWavy#1}}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\doubleUnderWavy{%
    I am using the wave underline to highlight some text, but there is no function to make a line break. Each time the text was always underlined in a single line. Is there any methods to use \textbackslash dwave and have the line break result?%
}
\end{document}
```

Just copy the definition of `\underWavy` from the documentation of `lua-ul` and modify accordingly.

[image: output image]