# soul package for wavy underline with bidi does not compile

Tags: xetex, soul, bidi

I am using the soul+tikz code provided by Gonzalo Medina in [Red squiggly imitation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80378/red-squiggly-imitation)
to get a wavy underline
All works well until I include the raqgged2e and bidi packages. At compile time I get

! Improper discretionary list.
\SOUL@everyhyphen ...e] \highlight@EndHighlight ;}

Any ideas on how to resolve this? or a soul and bidi just incompatible in this case?

Comment: Update: I did a complete package upgr of my texlife env but it did not resolve it. When using only ragged2e it compiles, but output is messy: wavy underline ends up vert. and there is vert space between the words. I tried ulem before but noticed the wavy underline does not align well. It extends into following space, or starts a bit before the word. I did some more googling and came across the tcolorbox package. I now have a wavy underline created by stripping as much of the box/frame as possible and then putting a wav underline as the bottom line using overlay.