# Jagged underline in listing

Tags: listings, underline

I'm trying to mark some code in a `listing` as erroneous with a typical jagged red underline.

[image]

Ideally, this would be the output of the following code.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
12 + ~[1, 2]~
\end{lstlisting}
```

### What I tried so far

- I found code to create a jagged underline [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80424/149123). For the image above, I used the command `\MarkText[red][1pt][2pt]{$[1, 2]$}`.
- I found out that the `listing` option `moredelim=**[is][...]{~}{~}` can be used to add the wanted functionality to the `lstlisting` environment, where `...` should be an appropriate mark-up command.

Unfortunately, filling in `\MarkText[red][1pt][2pt]` for the dots results in obscure error messages. I'm not sure how to continue.

MWE (almost all code is there to define the `\MarkText` command, you can skip to the part `%%% START %%%` to get a quick overview):

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%% CODE FOR \MarkText MACRO %%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newlength\LineWidth
\newlength\Amplitude
\newlength\SegLength

\setlength\LineWidth{0.4pt}
\setlength\Amplitude{1pt}
\setlength\SegLength{5pt}

\definecolor{HLcolor}{RGB}{240,0,0}

% The following code contains a variation of the great code by Antal S-Z
% in his answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/3954
%in TeX.SX

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\highlight@DoHighlight}{
  \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,decorate,decoration={zigzag,amplitude=\Amplitude,segment length=\SegLength}]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,-2pt)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,-2pt)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@BeginHighlight}{
  \coordinate (begin highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@EndHighlight}{
  \coordinate (end highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newdimen\highlight@previous
\newdimen\highlight@current

\DeclareRobustCommand*\highlight[1][]{%
  \SOUL@setup
  %
  \def\SOUL@preamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \highlight@EndHighlight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@postamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@EndHighlight
      \highlight@DoHighlight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyhyphen{%
    \discretionary{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
      \SOUL@sethyphenchar
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
    \hbox{##1}%
    \discretionary{%
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everysyllable{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \path let \p0 = (begin highlight), \p1 = (0,0) in \pgfextra
        \global\highlight@previous=\y0
        \global\highlight@current =\y1
      \endpgfextra (0,0) ;
      \ifdim\highlight@current < \highlight@previous
        \highlight@DoHighlight
        \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \the\SOUL@syllable
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
  }%
  \SOUL@
}
\makeatother

\DeclareDocumentCommand\MarkText{O{red}O{1pt}O{5pt}m}{%
  \colorlet{HLcolor}{#1}
  \setlength\Amplitude{#2}%
  \setlength\SegLength{#3}%
  \tikzmark{endquote}\tikzmark{beginquote}\highlight{#4}%
}


%%%%%% START %%%%%%%%

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
      moredelim=**[is][\MarkText[red][1pt][2pt]]{~}{~}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
12 + ~[1, 2]~
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```