# Tikz - Box with title box on top

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm quite new to tikz but I'm looking for the right commmands to make a box like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can use multi part shape or `tcolorbox`, but please show us, what you try so far.

Comment: For the red squiggly line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80424/47927 =)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
title=TITLE,
colback=white,colframe=gray!30,coltitle=black,
sharp corners,
fonttitle=\centering\bfseries\sffamily,
]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]