# How to emulate justified, non-hyphenated environment from Word/Adobe/etc.?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation, alignment, ragged2e, hyphenat

I would like to emulate a 'justify' environment as seen in most WYSIWYG editors.

- Each line should extend its spacing to fit the maximum possible width.
- No words should be hyphenated. (Using \hbox or *hyphenat* has not worked due to items extending over the page margins).

How do I achieve this? I've had no luck so far with *ragged2e*.

[image: Example of justified paragraph in Microsoft Word.]

Comment: `\hyphenchar=-1`  will disable hyphention, you probably need `\sloppy` to compensate but are you sure you want that? Surely even Word uses hyphenation doesn't it? (I don't use it myself but I assume it does?)

Comment: The answers to this question may help: [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why one would strive for bad typesetting such as what you get from word processors when you disable hyphenation.

Anyway…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Calibri}

% how to obtain bad typesetting
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
%%%

\frenchspacing % no extended end-of-sentence space

\begin{document}

%%%
% just to reproduce your column width, not something
% to be used in real documents
\settowidth{\hsize}{Contrary to popular belief, Lorem ipsum}
%%%

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might have added the [red squigglies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80378/15036) !